# Does JSON schema have any standards or conventions for associating an instance document with the schema to which it conforms?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am new to Json Schema, but have worked a lot with xsd's (xml schemas) in the past.
With xml schema it is possible to tag an element in one's xml document
with the 'schemaLocation' attribute. This attribute can be used by a validating xml
parser to verify that the content and structure of the element conforms to its associated 
schema.     In xml you do something like this:

```
<animal 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.zippy.com 
        http://foo.bar.com/animal.xsd">
    type="dog"
    name="rover"/>
```

I am wondering: is there some standard way to do this in JSON schema?
I could not find anything in the specification or 
the tutorials I went through.
I am hoping there might be something like this:

```
{
    "schema": "http://foo.bar.com/animal.schema.json",

    "animal": {
        "type": "dog",
        "name": "rover",
    }
}
```

My goal is to have each JSON document that my REST service returns include an annotation 
(an attribute "schema",  or something similar)    pointing to the schema 
that validates that particular instance... Then I can optionally launch the service in a 'verification
mode' wherein it automatically validates outbound responses to make sure they conform to the schema.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way for a JSON document to identify the schema that describes it. One of the design goals of JSON Schema is that it impose nothing on the structure of the JSON document being validated.

However, JSON Schema does define a way to link a JSON Schema to a document in the context of an HTTP response. You can use the `describedby` Link header to identify the schema.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Link: <http://foo.bar.com/animal.schema.json>; rel="describedby"

{
    "animal": {
        "type": "dog",
        "name": "rover"
    }
}
```

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.10.1